# cast string to array<float64> in standard-sql

Tags: google-bigquery

I've imported a csv into a table in BigQuery, and some columns hold a string which really should be a list of floats.
So now i'm try to convert these strings to some arrays. Thanks to SO I've managed to convert a string to a list of floats, but now i get one row by element of the list, instead of 1 row by initial row ie the array is "unnested". But it's a problem as it would generate a huge amount of duplicated data. Would someone please now how to do the conversion from `STRING` to `ARRAY<FLOAT64>` please?

partial code:

```
with tbl as (
  select "id1" as id, 
  "10000\t10001\t10002\t10003\t10004" col1_str, 
  "10000\t10001.1\t10002\t10003\t10004" col2_str 
)
select id, cast(elem1 as float64) col1_floatarray, cast(elem2 as float64) col2_floatarray
from tbl
, unnest(split(col1_str, "\t")) elem1
, unnest(split(col2_str, "\t")) elem2
```

expected:
1 row, with 3 columns of types `STRING` id, `ARRAY<FLOAT64>` col1_floatarray, `ARRAY<FLOAT64>` col2_floatarray

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below

```
select id, 
  array(select cast(elem as float64) from unnest(split(col1_str, "\t")) elem) col1_floatarray, 
  array(select cast(elem as float64) from unnest(split(col2_str, "\t")) elem) col2_floatarray
from tbl
```

if applied to sample data in y our question - output is

[image]

Comment: and it works. thank you, again! obviously i'm a little confused about the positioning of `unnest` either in the select part or in the from part...